# Django-pipeline and javascript dependencies

Tags: javascript, django, coffeescript, requirejs

I'm working on a Django project that uses Django-pipeline for assets, and I keep having issues where I define something in one javascript file that is required by another file, but the second file gets loaded before the first and thus the second file fails to load properly. I can mess with the order things get included into PIPELINE_JS but this is pretty awkward to deal with. In most languages you can do things like `require foo` to make sure that foo is defined but it seems like with javascript and django-pipeline this isn't possible. I've looked into RequireJS a little but I'm not sure how whether I can use it with django-pipeline. What should I do in this case? What do others who use django-pipeline or django in general do for javascript dependency management?

As a side note, I'm actually using Coffeescript, not straight Javascript, but that doesn't seem to help things any. In rails I could do `#= require 'foo'` to require another coffeescript file but that seems to be linked to the rails asset pipeline.

Comment: Are those two file in a separate group ? Can you provide your ``PIPELINE_JS`` settings ?

Comment: Mostly in the same group. The PIPELINE_JS is essentially a bunch of groups which are primarily formed by globbing some directories using glob2.glob.

In some directory I have content.coffee which depends on utils.coffee, for instance, and so far I haven't found a way to indicate within content.coffee that utils.coffee should be loaded before it. An ideal solution for me would not require messing with the order of strings in PIPELINE_JS because if I later add another file which depends on utils.coffee I'd have to go dive into that file again.

Comment: Also hi @cyberdelia! Thanks for responding to my question! Exciting when the author of a library responds to your question on Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to order `'source_filenames'` list accordingly, also remember that those file will be concatenated in this order when running `collectstatic`.

Pipeline will respect this order, it will also avoid duplicate so that your are safe when doing this :

```
'base.coffee',
'*.coffee',
```

There is no "require" syntax for now in django-pipeline.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I could put the more important files in the list separately before the globbing. That's not really the answer I was hoping for, but I guess it solves my immediate problem.